# Running performance tools using RBAC

Tags: rbac, perf, ebpf

I recently started a job that will involve a lot of performance tweaking.

I was wondering whether tools like eBPF and perf can be used with RBAC? Or will full root access be required? Getting root access might be difficult. We're mainly using fairly old Linux machines - RHEL 6.5. I'm not too familiar with RBAC. It home I have used Dtrace on Solaris, macOS and FreeBSD, but there I have the root password.

Comment: RHEL allows use of perf tool: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-analyzperf-perf and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/perf-using. To get profiles and statistics (`perf stat`) of own user-space programs you need capability of debugging the target process. sysctl `kernel.perf_event_paranoid` value will limit perf usage for users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability for cpu events or kernel profiling. Check your `sysctl kernel.perf_event_paranoid` and kernel version.

Comment: Thanks, that's the sort of information that I was looking for. You should make this comment an answer. Do you know if the situation is similar with eBPF?

Comment: For eBPF, [most program types](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/syscall.c?h=v5.5#n1736) (including all types related to tracing like kprobes, perf events or tracepoints) need `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` too. Also I believe RHEL only supports eBPF [in version 7.6+](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introduction-ebpf-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7). Not sure what tracing tools are available to non-root :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEL lists several profiling and tracing solutions for RHEL6 including perf in its 
[Performance Tuning Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/index) and [Developer Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/index):
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-analyzperf-perf
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/perf-using

[Chapter 3. Monitoring and Analyzing System Performance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/main-analyzeperf) of [Performance Tuning Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/index)  mentions several tools: Gnome System Monitor, KDE System Guard, Performance Co-Pilot (PCP), top/ps/vmstat/sar, tuned and ktune, MRG Tuna, and application profilers SystemTap, Oprofile, Valgrind (which is not real profiler, but cpu emulator with instruction and cache event counting), perf.

[Chapter 5. Profiling](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/profiling) of  [Developer Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/index) lists Valgrind, oprofile, SystemTap, perf, and ftrace.

Usually profiling of kernel or whole system is allowed only for root, or for user with CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability. Some profiling is limited by sysctl variables

- kernel.perf_event_paranoid  (documented in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt):

> ```
> perf_event_paranoid:
> ```
>
> Controls use of the performance events system by unprivileged
>       users (without CAP_SYS_ADMIN).  The default value is 2.
>
> ```
>  -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users
>      Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK
> >=0: Disallow ftrace function tracepoint by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
>      Disallow raw tracepoint access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
> >=1: Disallow CPU event access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
> >=2: Disallow kernel profiling by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN
> ```

- kernel.kptr_restrict (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt), which also change perf ability to profile kernel

> ```
> kptr_restrict:
>
> This toggle indicates whether restrictions are placed on
> exposing kernel addresses via /proc and other interfaces.
> ```

More recent versions of ubuntu and rhel (7.4) has also kernel.yama.ptrace_scope http://security-plus-data-science.blogspot.com/2017/09/some-security-updates-in-rhel-74.html

> ... use  kernel.yama.ptrace_scope to set who can ptrace. The different
>   values have the following meaning:
>
> ```
> # 0 - Default attach security permissions.
> # 1 - Restricted attach. Only child processes plus normal permissions.
> # 2 - Admin-only attach. Only executables with CAP_SYS_PTRACE.
> # 3 - No attach. No process may call ptrace at all. Irrevocable until next boot.
> ```
>
> You can temporarily set it like this:
>
> ```
>  echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
> ```

To profile a program you should have access to debugging it, like attaching with `gdb` (ptrace capability) or `strace`. I don't know RHEL or [its RBAC](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/identity_management_guide/defining-roles) so you should check what is available to you. Generally perf profiling of own userspace programs on software events is available for more cases. Access to per-process cpu hardware counters, profiling of programs of other users, profiling of kernel is more limited. I can expect that correctly enabled RBAC should not allow you or root to profile kernel, as perf can inject tracing probes and leak information from kernel or other users.

Qeole says in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346087/running-performance-tools-using-rbac?noredirect=1#comment106766402_60346087) that eBPF is not implemented for RHEL6 ([added in RHEL7.6](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introduction-ebpf-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7); with [XDP - eXpress Data Path in RHEL8](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/tag/ebpf/)), so you only can try ftrace for tracing or stap (SystemTap) for advanced tracing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll take a look at the links. I haven't yet tried eBPF - I only came across it when I looked at Brendan Gregg's web page when researching profiling solutions and noticed that he has done a lot of work using eBPF. At work I'll see what I can access machine wise. Whilst the officially blessed development machines are running RHEL 6.5 there are probably a few available with other OSes and/or RHEL versions.